# Use Adobe Typekit fonts in Google Docs?

Tags: adobe, google-docs, google-font-api, typekit

Is there a way to use Adobe Typekit fonts in Google Docs? I'm using Typekit and have a few really nice fonts that I would like to use in my Google Docs too, but can't seem to find them in Google's font library. Is there a way to add Adobe Typekit fonts to Google Docs?